# Lower than caracter in json object send to php

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, special-characters

I'm programing with jquery an ajax call like that :

```
       mi_json['textarea_anamnesis_proxima'] = 'Ex+lab+270721\nGOT+48,+GPT+48,+GGT+124+(>),+FA+139+(>)\nPCR+1.3+(<)+|+;+as+a+asacdfd+dfd+weaewe+we+´+++as+as+as+as+asqwq+qwq+qw\ngsdff+\nfdfsfsf+sfs+sdf+sdf+sdfs+er+aadase+ase\n'; 

       console.log(mi_json);

          $.ajax({                                      
            url: 'graba_consult2.php',
            data: mi_json,
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
            {
              console.log("->"+data+"<-");
            }
            });
```

But i have a problem with the value of data arriving at PHP :

```
data= "Ex+lab+270721
GOT+48,+GPT+48,+GGT+124+(>),+FA+139+(>)
PCR+1.3+(Ex+lab+270721<br />
GOT+48,+GPT+48,+GGT+124+(&gt;),+FA+139+(&gt;)<br />
PCR+1.3+("
```

I found that the "<" sign is cutting the value of the json value. Why ? How can i resolve that problem please ?

Comment: `the value of the json value`...there is no JSON here

Comment: Anyway it seems like something is happening somewhere which attempts to interpret that data as HTML - the newline `\n` has been converted to `<br>`, and then there is the problem with the `<`. But none of the code you've shown would be causing that. I would guess it's in the PHP somewhere, but you haven't provided us with that info.

Comment: This is my PHP : `$data_length=4000;
echo substr($json_object2->textarea_anamnesis_proxima,0,$data_length);`

Comment: i found the solution : add a space character after the "<" sign.

Comment: That doesn't explain how `\n` got converted to `<br/>` though. `substr()` wouldn't do that. That can't be all your PHP. How was `$json_object2->textarea_anamnesis_proxima` created, for example?